# GCM Sent messages before subscribing

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I just implemented Google Cloud Messaging successfully in my Android application and to test it I sent some messages from my server, that worked perfectly.

I was wondering what happens if I send a message to an specific topic and then a device subscribes to that topic, will it receive the message?

Will my users receive the messages I sent while I was testing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found this behavior defined in the GCM documentation.  My experience (version 8.3.0) has been that when a client subscribes to a topic, it does **not** receive messages previously sent to that topic.  Although messages have a default [time_to_live](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) of 4 weeks, server processing to hold the message and send it later is only applied to devices that have subscribed but are not able to receive the message because they are turned off or do not have a network connection.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what happens, because I tested it in other devices and they never the old messages.